# Why I am not able to assign Default value ot my property using MVC2 in my asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this code in my class

```
[MetadataType(typeof(HipaaBenefit_Metadata))]
    public partial class HipaaBenefit
    {
        public class HipaaBenefit_Metadata
        {
            [DefaultValue("")]
            public string TimePeriodQualifierEb06 { get; set; }

            [DefaultValue("")]
            public string NetworkIndicatorEb12 { get; set; }

            [DefaultValue("")]
            public string BenefitAmountEb07 { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

In my Database table these columns are not null fields. when I am trying to save the data from  codebehid to table I am trying to assign these column values as Empty.String.

But some reasons I am not able to send this Empty.String values to the table?

is that something I am doing wrong in this code? if so how to assign the default values?

Thanks

Comment: what happens when you try and save the values? is an exception thrown?

Comment: yes its throwing an Exception can not insert the value in to null columns.

Comment: Can you please post the exact exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tryied to set default value as NULL?

[DefaultValue("Null")]

Comment: `"Null"` is a string an not `null` value